# Need suggestions on which plugin to install from eclipse market?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, plugins, pde

I am developing a new plugin in eclipse. I need a plugin from internet (for eclipse, of course) which I can dissect and understand its implementation (by looking into plugin.xml etc.). It would help me create my own plugin.
I want your help in suggesting some plug-ins which I download and dissect, so that i can use that logic to make my own plugin?

I will now give an insight to my proposed plugin:::
My plugin would take in some input via a GUI interface from the user and then I should be able to convert all the user input into a text file and trigger a perl script. It sounds sloppy, but I am completely new to Eclipse and Plugins.

I just need some suggestions from you experts.

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: What do you mean by 'some input via a GUI interface'?  Text editor, graphical model editor?

Comment: You should find some resources how to develop Eclipse plugins from scratch. Looking at the result (the delivered plugin) gives you no indication in which order what is created, tested and delivered. Have a look at [Developing Eclipse](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html), [Eclipse Plugin Development](http://www.eclipsepluginsite.com/) and others. Then you have to find the right extension points to reach what you want to do. Good luck :-)

Comment: The PDE also provides Templates when creating a New Plug-In Project that include UI examples.

Comment: What does the title of the question have to do with the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you download either the Eclipse Classic package or the Eclipse for RCP Developers package, they include source for Eclipse itself. You can use the Eclipse plugins themselves as examples.